# import JSON file to SOLR with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, solr

I need to import a JSON file to a (local) SOLR host with PHP.
I'm trying to use the php `cUrl` to send something but I'm not that well in php.

**My Code for sending a request to get a result from solr already worked:**

```
// ...
$url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q="test"~1&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=2000';
$curl = curl_init();

// set cUrl options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-type:application/json"),
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$login:password"
));

$contents = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
$docs = $data['response']['docs'];
// ...
```

But **how can I import/index a JSON file to my solr host with cUrl?**

Comment: have you tried setting the `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`? I wish i was at work right now I could walk through this with you...

Comment: I saw something with that yes. Someone wrote, that you need to set `CURLOPT_POST` to `true` and send the data in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. I need to read the file and save it with json_decode and then put this to my POSTFIELDS, right?